# JAXB and document object

Tags: java, jaxb

I am getting object of type `org.w3c.dom.Document` from a source (basically a parsed xml document - java object). I want to use this xml document object to create java objects using JAXB. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can unmarshal directly from DOM objects, this includes a `org.w3c.dom.Document`:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29

If you need to specify the type of object you are unmarshalling, then you can wrap the DOM node in a `javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource` and use the following API:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20java.lang.Class%29

Comment: Did @bdoughan implement javax/xml and make it his mission to teach the internet how to use it???

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head you could just convert the `Document` to a `Stream` and use the `Unmarshaller` to convert to the `JAXB` instance you need.

Something like:

```
MyJAXB o = (MyJAXB)unmarshaller.unmarshall(new StringReader(arrayoutsream.tostring()));
```

**Disclaimer**: Haven't even bothered to see if this compiles but you should understand how to approach this

Comment: FYI - JAXB (JSR-222) has APIs for unmarshalling directly from DOM nodes:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9464111/383861